# File get save under some Unknown Path in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse and have the following folder structure:

[Eclipse Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWIat.png)

In UserHelper.java i have the code

```
try {
  File file = new File ("vikvik1.JSON");

  if (!file.exists ()) {

    System.out.println ("No file");
    file.createNewFile ();
    temp = true;
  }

  System.out.println (file.getAbsolutePath ());

} catch (IOException ioe) {
  System.out.println ("Exception occurred:");
  ioe.printStackTrace ();
}
```

But after creating the file, the output is `C:\Users\a595649\Documents\Vikram Thakur\Soft\eclipse\vikvik1.JSON`
This is the location where my Eclipse Exe file is stored.

How can I get this File saved under my project DBnov folder ?

Comment: java is not the same as javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide the path of your file while instantiating the File object, otherwise java select it per default. 
See the javadoc for the constructor, you can initiate it different ways, for example with the path as String:

```
File file = new File ("your_path", "vikvik1.JSON");
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

- create a property file under your classpath, say foo.properties
- put there a property like

  ```
  basePath=/some/path/you/want/to/use
  ```
- Read the property file

  ```
  String basePath="";

  final Properties properties = new Properties();
  try (final InputStream stream =
     this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties")) {

  properties.load(stream);
  basePath=properties.getProperty("basePath");
  }
  ```
- Read your file

  ```
  File file = new File ("basePath","vikvik1.JSON");
  ```